# How to launch Angular 2 Application locally as npm start doesnot working

Tags: angular, npm-start

I followed the below mention link to setup local environment and launch application.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html

When I used npm start command to launch application, it throws an error.
In the guide it is mentioned that npm start doesnot work

***'npm start fails in Bash for Windows which does not support networking to servers as of January, 2017.'***

Then can you please let me know how can I launch the Angular application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative solution is to use the angular-cli, which I think the best way to start a new angular project. Here's the [link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cli-quickstart.html) in the official docs.
Creating new projects in angular-cli is simple as this

`ng new app-name`

Comment: Thanks @brijmcq. I am able to start the angular 2 application with the help   of this link https://github.com/angular/angular-cli and your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Run it in the console ... not in "Bash for windows".

I successfully run my Angular apps with npm start.

Comment: Thanks @DeborahK. I am executing npm start in command prompt. Are you mentioning command prompt as Console.

Answer (score 1):

Which IDE are you using. I use VS Code and there you have integrated terminal console. Run `npm start` and it should run your application.You can also use command prompt inside your project folder where package.json resides to start your application by running cmd `npm start`.